# Excel VBA - IF Autofilter Contains No Records, MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter a specific criteria, in this case *Anything Like -SERVICE CODE* I am filtering this within the column name as opposed to the column being represented by A:A. The FIrst part of code works fine, the If statement is where I am having issues. I created the If statement to be able to Do something if there is an Actual Row of Data that shows for the filter of -SERVICE CODE, in this instance it should show "Data" if there is at least one line that is filtered, the problem is that it shows the "Data" message even if there is nothing that is shown when Filtered.

I am trying to figure out how to get the Msg of No Data to show correctly when there is nothing that is matching the Filter Criteria.

Thank you,

```
Sub Filter results()

Dim rng As Range, res As Variant

Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Rows(1)
res = Application.Match("Errors", rng, 0)
rng.AutoFilter Field:=res, Criteria1:="*-SERVICE CODE*"

If rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
   MsgBox "Data"
Else
   MsgBox "No Data"
End If

End Sub()
```

Comment: So you always have cells in `rng`? If so the `Count` function returns the number of cells, irrespective of having data in them or not perhaps? Not sure, just a suggestion. Can you comment what the `rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` returns?

Comment: Looks like `rng` is the header row, therefore it's always visible and always returns more than 1. Change the range of visible cells you are counting to `A:A` and it should work fine.

Comment: @AER Hello, it returns just the header row if the criteria does not have a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, I defined the last row of your used range (assuming there is always data in column A, change to another column if not) as any cells beyond the last row will appear as visible. Then the visible count is only performed on that column up to the last row.

```
Sub FilterResults()

Dim rng As Range, res As Variant, lrow As Long

Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Rows(1)
res = Application.Match("Errors", rng, 0)
rng.AutoFilter Field:=res, Criteria1:="*-SERVICE CODE*"

lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, res).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, res), Cells(lrow, res)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
   MsgBox "Data"
Else
   MsgBox "No Data"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Made an edit, tested and is working on my machine: `.cells.count`

Comment: This worked, I had to change the Number after Count to correlate with the number of the Column, in this case Column U which is "21". Follow up question, is there a way to make this work based off of Column Names? These columns change frequently and when a new user uses the report I want the maintenance to be minimal, therefor, instead of referencing Columns U1:U is there a way to reference it by name? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Moved the `lrow` calculation and made it affect `res` column number, it now counts the last error message as the last row, but since that is all you are looking for it works. the if statement has been modified to count the column `res` too.

Comment: Added +1 to lrow to stop error where there is no data at all in the column

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

you could use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, rng.Resize(, 1))` to test how many cells have been filtered and check there are more than one (headers get always filtered) in a column

like in this little refactoring of your code

```
Sub FilterResults()
    Dim res As Variant

    With ActiveSheet.Rows(1)
        res = Application.Match("Errors", .Cells, 0)
        If Not IsError(res) Then
            .AutoFilter Field:=res, Criteria1:="*-SERVICE CODE*"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell filtered other than header (which is in row 3)
               MsgBox "Data"
               With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                   ' code
               End With
            Else
               MsgBox "No Data"
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @MrLockett, did you try this?